# Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, login

**Este es el código que utilizo,** 
**esta es la función donde hago la consulta a DB[image: captura del código]**

Comment: Y cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: Podrías subir el código por favor

Comment: Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in

Comment: este es el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te sea util, te falta recuperar esos resultados,
en este ejemplo usé mysqli_fetch_assoc:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$this->usuario' AND pass='$this->contrasena'";

$consult = $con->query($sql);

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consult);

if($result > 0){

    return $result;

} else {
    // No hay resultados
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funcionó, estoy revisando la API de mysqli para no dejar pasar esos detalles ...